# iterate function in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, loops

How can be `iterate` function modified that the result will be

```
f x, (f^2)x, (f^4)x, (f^8)x, ...
```

I'd be very happy if anybody could provide me with any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given, that `f^x` means `f` x-times applied to `x` I would say

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = f x : iterate (f . f) x
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
Prelude> map snd $ iterate (\(f,x) -> (f.f, f x)) ((+1),1)
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,...
```